# Testing-library fireEvent.change doesn't works with <Select native> from MUI

Tags: material-ui, react-testing-library

I have component with  element:

```
<Select
  native
  role="combobox"
  aria-label="select height"
  value={ height.toString() }
  onChange={ handleChangeHeight }
>
```

When I try to make a test with changing the value it do nothing:

```
fireEvent.change(heightSelect, {target: {value: "500"}})
```

But if I replace element for standard test is working.

```
<select role="combobox" aria-label="select height" value=... >
```

How I can fix this problem with testing-library for @mui/material ?

Answer (score 0):

fixed:

```
const heightSelect = screen.getByRole('combobox', { name: 'height select' })    
const select = heightSelect.childNodes[0]
fireEvent.change(select, {target: {value: 500}})
const selectedNew = within(heightSelect).getAllByRole('option', {selected: true})[0]
expect(selectedNew.innerHTML).toBe(`height 500 mm`)
```